# How to jump to anchor tag on php page after html form submits

Tags: php, html, forms, get, anchor

My index.php page uses a template called template.html, and this html file has a form in it. The first line of the form is:

```
<form name="search" method="get" action="thumbnails.php?#myAnchor">
```

thumbnails.php also uses template.html as a template. When a user submits the form on the index page, I want it to redirect to thumbnails.php (as it does now) but then go to the anchor I've written in template.html like this:

```
 <a name="myAnchor"></a>
```

You can test it for yourself below, just search for "nature" in the top search box and it'll redirect you to the top of thumbnails.php but I want it to scroll down to the anchor tag embedded in the template file (seen in thumbnails.php source code) -- [My Site](http://www.taskbasket.net/gallery)

Here is the link to [thumbnails.php](http://taskbasket.net/gallery/thumbnails.php) 
and here's the link to [template.html](http://taskbasket.net/gallery/themes/matheso/template.html)

I've read tons of solutions but nothing seems to work. Ideas?? Thank you

Comment: Use of `<a name="">` is now obsolete, use `<anything id="">` instead.

Comment: No. After form submit, always redirect to another page or another instance of same page to avoid double submit. In that redirect you could use the `#` but you do not include the `#` in the form action *nor ever* stay on the page that the form submits to but always redirect.

Comment: You also *never* include the `?` in the form action. That will be appended on form submit. Any parameter you put like `?x=y` in the form action is likely to be stripped off in some browsers.

Comment: look up the POST-redirect-GET pattern. Staying on the URL you submitted the form to is dangerous. Consider a stupid bank that does this after you submit a "withdraw life savings" transaction. You hit reload, and now you're transferring your life savings AGAIN, and end up in the hole by $everything_you_had.

Comment: @Dai, You have a reference for that claim?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm confused as to what I should replace in my code-- change what to what? My form doesn't redirect to the same page if that's what you're saying... the url goes from index.php to thumbnails.php -- except both these pages use template.html (which has the form + anchor tag).  What should I do specifically? Thanks

Comment: @developerwjk yes, the HTML5 specification removed the `name=""` attribute from the `<a>` element: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element (obsolete note: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#attr-a-name). The specification for fragment scrolling gives preference to `id` over `name` and only gives instructions for `name` attributes for backwards-compat ( http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#scroll-to-fragid )

Comment: After you process the submitted form, `header('Location: thumbnails.php?#myAnchor'); return;` Make sure not to print anything before doing this.

Comment: have you test this `<a name="myAnchor" id="myAnchor"></a>` ?

Answer (score 0):

As [Dai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/159145/dai) said [in their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27828037/how-to-jump-to-anchor-tag-on-php-page-after-html-form-submits?rq=1#comment44065619_27828037),

> [...] the HTML5 specification removed the name="" attribute from the
>   [`<a>` element](http://w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) ([obsolete note](http://w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#attr-a-name)). [The specification for
>   fragment scrolling](http://w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#scroll-to-fragid) gives preference to id over name and only gives
>   instructions for name attributes for backwards-compatibility.

In your code you have to add an `id` attribute to your anchor in template.html:

```
<a name="myAnchor" id="myAnchor"></a>
```